# Dojo dateTextInput

Tags: dojo, datepicker

I have a dateTextInput and have added a constraint to pick only a date in the future, the issue i have here is earlier it used to be a text box where users had to enter date in the format mm/dd/yy [yeah i nearly killed myself when i saw it], i dont have the permissions to edit the service so all i need to do is send text the same way it used to receive earlier.

Basically there is a package with all the javascript that has a getById that retrieves 'value', i want the value to be given in the mm/dd/yy format.

Possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Dojo seems to have a feature that will let you *display* 2-digit years, but not *retrieve* them that way:

> Sometimes you may want to input and display years in a format with only 2-digit years. Note the server still needs the full 4-digit year sent on form submit so that it’s not ambiguous. There is a constraints property fullYear (boolean) that controls the presentation of the year as 2 digits or 4. The catch is that this can only be set after the widget has been created.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html#working-with-two-digit-years

However, you can call `get("value")` on the DateTextBox and it will give you a JavaScript Date object. You can either use the built-in methods or your favorite date library to convert it to whatever String format you like: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp